# Load lazy collection in ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I would like to query all products for a company. The products should be loaded with the list of countries. I managed to write a Spring JPA repository method to query what I want but I wonder **why I need a DISTINCT clause**.

If I run the following query, I get one product per country. So if a product has 3 countries, the query will return the same 3 rows. **Can you explain why?**

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = "countries", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
List<Product> findByCompanyIdOrderByIdAsc(Long companyId);
```

So to fix that issue I added a Distinct clause which return what I want.

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = "countries", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
List<Product> findDistinctByCompanyIdOrderByIdAsc(Long companyId);
```

I have the same issue if I run a JPQL `Select p from Product LEFT JOIN FETCH p.countries WHERE p.company.id = ?1` which is equivalent to `findByCompanyIdOrderByIdAsc`.

The entities:

```
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    private Company company;

    @ManyToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "product_country",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id",
        resolver = EntityIdResolver.class, scope = Country.class)
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    private Set<Country> countries = new HashSet<>();

}

public class Country implements Serializable {
}
```